# 2 D3.js force layout graphs on same page?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

i am trying to have 2 d3.js force layout graphs on same page , created by one script only. I also applied various events on them. But one working on one graph, the same actions also applies to another, which i don't need.

I am not able to maintain the individuality between them.
How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create separate force layouts for them and keep the nodes and links that are assigned to each separate. That is, each should have their own `d3.layout.force()`, the intersection between the sets of nodes for each should be empty and there should be no links between them.

Answer (score 0):

try to use the same SVG for both to draw graphs in the same page